# Why this code produces invalid alignment with MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, memory-alignment

I have tested this code on ideone.com and it outputs `16` as it should. However when I try it in Visual Studio 2013 it shows `8`. Is it a bug or lack of C++11 support from the compiler?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;
using float_pack = aligned_storage<4 * sizeof(float), 16>::type;
int main() {

    cout << alignment_of<float_pack>::value << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have used alignment_of because MSVC doesn't support `alignof`.

**Edit:** I see that I can't get `16` alignment with `aligned_storage`. But why this snippet is ok?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <xmmintrin.h>
using namespace std;

__declspec(align(16)) struct float_pack {
    float x[4];
};

int main()
{
    cout << alignment_of<float_pack>::value << endl;
}
```

Output is `16`. Does that mean that compiler can provide larger alignment when using extensions? Why I can't achieve the same result with `aligned_storage`? Only because MSVC doesn't provide that with `aligned_storage`?

Comment: Support for over-aligned types is implementation-defined in practically all contexts.  The maximum fundamental alignment when compiling for x86 using Visual C++ is 8 bytes.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis is that documented anywhere, I would like to add that to my answer if it is.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour:  `<cstddef>` defines `std::max_align_t` to be type `double`, and `sizeof(double) == 8`.

Comment: 20.9.7.6 "`Align` shell be equal to `alignof(T)` for some type `T`." So this code is not standard-compliant if there is no standard-provided type with 16-byte alignment.

Comment: MSVC of course knows about SSE's `__m128` type, so there _is_ in fact a type with alignment > `alignof(std::max_align_t)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `std::max_align_t` is `8`, [see it live](http://rextester.com/TNU94621):

```
std::cout << alignment_of<std::max_align_t>::value << '\n';
```

In the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `3.11` *Alignment* it says:

> A fundamental alignment is represented by an alignment less than or equal to the greatest alignment sup- ported by the implementation in all contexts, which is equal to alignof(std::max_align_t) (18.2).[...]

Which says that that is the max alignment the implementation supports, this seems to be backed up by this [boost doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/align/vocabulary.html) which says:

> An extended alignment is represented by an alignment greater than alignof(std::max_align_t). It is implementation-defined whether any extended alignments are supported and the contexts in which they are supported. A type having an extended alignment requirement is an over-aligned type.

`max_align_t` is by the standard tied to the fundamental alignment which James as informed us is `8 bytes`. Whereas an extension does not have to stick to this as long as it is documented which if we read the docs for [__declspec align](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx) we see that it says:

> Writing applications that use the latest processor instructions
>   introduces some new constraints and issues. In particular, many new
>   instructions require that data must be aligned to 16-byte boundaries.
>   Additionally, by aligning frequently used data to the cache line size
>   of a specific processor, you improve cache performance. For example,
>   if you define a structure whose size is less than 32 bytes, you may
>   want to align it to 32 bytes to ensure that objects of that structure
>   type are efficiently cached.
>
> [...]
>
> Without __declspec(align(#)), Visual C++ aligns data on natural
>   boundaries based on the size of the data, for example 4-byte integers
>   on 4-byte boundaries and 8-byte doubles on 8-byte boundaries. Data in
>   classes or structures is aligned within the class or structure at the
>   minimum of its natural alignment and the current packing setting (from #pragma pack or the /Zp compiler option).

Answer (score 2):

`std::aligned_storage` defines a type of size `Len`, with the alignment requirement you provide. If you ask for an unsupported alignment, your program is ill-formed.

```
template <std::size_t Len, std::size_t Align
    = default-alignment > struct aligned_storage;
```

> Len shall not be zero. Align shall be equal to `alignof(T)` for some type `T` or to *default-alignment*.
>
> The value of *default-alignment* shall be the most stringent alignment requirement for any C++ object type whose size is no greater than `Len` (3.9). The member typedef type shall be a POD type suitable for use as uninitialized storage for any object whose size is at most `Len` and whose alignment is a divisor of `Align`.
>
> [ Note: A typical implementation would define aligned_storage as:

```
template <std::size_t Len, std::size_t Alignment>
struct aligned_storage {
    typedef struct {
        alignas(Alignment) unsigned char __data[Len];
    } type;
};
```

> —end note ]

And for `alignas`:

> #### 7.6.2 Alignment specifier [dcl.align]
>
> 1 An alignment-specifier may be applied to a variable or to a class data member, but it shall not be applied to a bit-field, a function parameter, the formal parameter of a catch clause (15.3), or a variable declared with the register storage class specifier. An alignment-specifier may also be applied to the declaration of a class or enumeration type. An alignment-specifier with an ellipsis is a pack expansion (14.5.3).
>   2 When the alignment-specifier is of the form alignas( assignment-expression ):
>   — the assignment-expression shall be an integral constant expression
>   — if the constant expression evaluates to a fundamental alignment, the alignment requirement of the
>   declared entity shall be the specified fundamental alignment
>   — if the constant expression evaluates to an extended alignment and the implementation supports that
>   alignment in the context of the declaration, the alignment of the declared entity shall be that alignment
>   — if the constant expression evaluates to an extended alignment and the implementation does not support
>   that alignment in the context of the declaration, the program is ill-formed
>   — if the constant expression evaluates to zero, the alignment specifier shall have no effect
>   — otherwise, the program is ill-formed.